# Reproject masked array with rasterio

Tags: python, numpy, landsat-8, resampling, rasterio

Is there a way to preserve the mask of a numpy array when reprojecting it with rasterio?
See the reproducible example with real data below:

```
import os
import tempfile

import rasterio
from rasterio.crs import CRS
from rasterio.warp import reproject, calculate_default_transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import requests

print(rasterio.__version__) #1.0a10

# Download function, only downloads the file once
def download(url):
    filename = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), os.path.basename(url))
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as dst:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                dst.write(chunk)
    return filename

# Download test data (14MB)
scene_id = 'LC08_L1TP_026047_20170616_20170629_01_T1'
url = 'https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/browse/gisready/landsat_8/%s.zip' % scene_id
archive = download(url)

# Read data as numpy array and apply mask
rgb = '/vsizip/%s/%s.tif' % (archive, scene_id)
mask = '/vsizip/%s/%s_QB.tif' % (archive, scene_id)
with rasterio.open(mask) as src:
    m = src.read(1)
with rasterio.open(rgb) as src:
    src_crs = src.crs
    src_transform = src.transform
    src_bounds = src.bounds
    src_width = src.width
    src_height = src.height
    red_array = np.ma.array(src.read(1), mask=m!=0)

# VIsualize masked array (clouds and cloud shadows are properly masked)
# plt.imshow(red_array)
# plt.show()

# Prepare destination array for warping
dst_crs = CRS({u'proj': u'laea', u'lon_0': -106, u'lat_0': 24}) # Equal area crs more or less centered on mexico center
dst_transform, dst_width, dst_height = calculate_default_transform(src_crs,
                                                                dst_crs,
                                                                src_width,
                                                                src_height,
                                                                *src_bounds,
                                                                resolution=(30, 30))
red_laea = np.ma.zeros((dst_height, dst_width), dtype=np.uint8)

# reproject array
reproject(source=red_array,
          destination=red_laea,
          src_transform=src_transform,
          src_crs=src_crs,
          dst_transform=dst_transform,
          dst_crs=dst_crs,
          dst_nodata=0)

# Visualize (clouds are no longer masked)
plt.imshow(red_laea)
plt.show()
```

What I would like/expect is that the mask (cloud and shadows in the example above) is transferred to the destination array. I was sort of expecting that behaviour from the description of the `src_nodata` argument (`rasterio.warp.reproject` function), but I may have misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 4):

Very nice example. I put it in a [notebook here](https://gist.github.com/j08lue/491f8d7c019928eab342e2f5bb090a33). I can reproduce your issue with `rasterio` `1.0a11`.

## Problems

Rasterio's reproject *does* intend to support masked arrays, but it seems to fail in this case.

1. One problem is that the `.fill_value` of your masked array is used as `src_nodata` (see these lines). That is wrong, because the actual `.data` in the masked array underneath the mask might have different values than `.fill_value`. But even filling the data underneath does not help.
2. Also, your `red_array.fill_value` is 999999, which is actually too large for the `red_array.dtype`, which is `uint8`. That is a big problem with NumPy's masked arrays problem. Even worse: taking a `.filled()` copy, you do not get an error but `63`...
3. The `reproject` function will not fill your destination with `np.ma.masked`. Especially not when you set `dst_nodata=0`. `dst_nodata=np.ma.masked` would be better, but fails due to dtype checking. So you will need to create a masked array from the returned data with something like

   ```
   red_laea[red_laea == dst_nodata] = np.ma.masked
   ```

## In summary

I can understand that you think you can use masked arrays with `rasterio.warp.reproject`, but it is not yet implemented well and masked arrays can have issues that are not easy to see (invalid `.fill_value`). So I recommend that you use regular arrays and keep track of the `nodata` value yourself. And consider raising an issue on `rasterio`.

[image: masked]